# How to create and save json template and snapshot in azure together(in storage)? And how to create a VMs from ARM and Snapshont?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-rm-template

How to create and save json template and snapshot in azure together(in storage)?  And how to create a VMs from ARM and Snapshont? (The question in the title) 
I have a json template and snapshot in azure. How I can save it in azure? And how I can deploy it from Azure ? I do this because my 1st vm has iis features and json template what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to create and save json tempalte and snapshot in azure together(in
>   storage)?

If you have VM deployed on the portal, you can [download the template for a VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/download-template) directly or copy the JSON code and paste it to a JSON file. Then create a storage account and container, and upload the files to the storage account following [these steps 1-4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/ps-template#create-the-files).

For a managed disk Snapshot, the snapshot is directly managed by Azure, you can [Export/Copy managed snapshots as VHD to a storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/scripts/virtual-machines-windows-powershell-sample-copy-snapshot-to-storage-account).

> And how to create a VMs from ARM and Snapshont?

You can [deploy the ARM template with PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/ps-template#create-the-resources).

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" -Name "myDeployment" -TemplateUri $templatePath -TemplateParameterUri $parametersPath
```

Also, you can [get more methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-deploy-portal) to deploy an ARM template on the Azure.

For the snapshot, you can create an image from snapshot first, then create a VM from this image, then restore your VM on the Azure portal, refer to [this](https://unitfly.com/blog/Azure-Create-VM-Image-and-Restore-VM-from-Image) doing this on the portal. Or you can see the sample in [Create a VM from a snapshot with PowerShell.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/scripts/virtual-machines-windows-powershell-sample-create-vm-from-snapshot?toc=%2Fpowershell%2Fmodule%2Ftoc.json)